# How should I take the sum of this infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

I'm working on a discrete probability distribution where N~pois($\lambda$>0) and X|N=n~binom(n,p). I need to find the sum of this infinite series:
$\frac{p^xe^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}\sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^{n-x}\lambda^{n-x}}{(n-x)!}$. This series apparently converges to $e^{\lambda(1-p)}$ (which makes sense since X~pois($\lambda p$)) but I am not sure how to demonstrate this.

I know the first few terms are $\frac{(1-p)^0\lambda^0}{1!}+\frac{(1-p)^{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\frac{(1-p)^{n-2}\lambda^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}+...$

Would this be something I could verify with the ratio test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sometimes useful to "push back" a series so that its starting index is zero.
$$
\frac{p^xe^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}\sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^{n-x}\lambda^{n-x}}{(n-x)!}=\frac{p^xe^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1-p)^{n}\lambda^{n}}{n!}
$$
$$
=\frac{p^xe^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^{n}}{n!}
$$Perhaps this reminds you more of $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$. You can show the series converges absolutely for any argument using the Ratio Test, and indeed the sum of the series is as you suggested.
$$
=\frac{p^xe^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} \cdot e^{(1-p)\lambda}
$$

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I was thinking along those lines with $e^z$ since, you know, complex analysis techniques. I'm new to this aspect of probability so I was hesitant to apply that technique. Since my bounds are $0\leq X=x \leq n$ that makes a lot of sense. Much appreciated!